# cURL command using java

Tags: java, httpclient

```
curl -F file=@/path/to/index.html -u lslkdfmkls@gmail.com -F 'data={"title":"API V1  App","package":"com.alunny.apiv1","version":"0.1.0","create_method":"file"}' https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps
```

I am trying to achieve the same using a java program using HttpClient library.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("build.phonegap.com", 443, "https"); 
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials( 
new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort(),AuthScope.ANY_REALM), 
new UsernamePasswordCredentials("abc@gmail.com", "abc123")); 

String authToken = "?auth_token=abcdefgh"; 

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps" + authToken ); 

String jsonString = "{\"title\":\"API V1 App\",\"create_method\":\"file\"}"; 
MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(); 
multipartEntity.addPart(new FormBodyPart("data", new StringBody(jsonString))); 
multipartEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File("C:/Users/Desktop/app.zip"))); 

/*StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonString, "UTF-8"); */
httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);  

System.out.println("executing request " + httpPost.getRequestLine()); 
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost); 
HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity(); 
System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine()); 
if(entity != null ){ 
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity)); 
}
```

In the above code I can only set StringEntity or FileEntity but not both and I think this is what is required to get the functionality of the curl command.

After trying with StringEntity and FileEntity I tried with MultipartEntity but no luck..
Can you please provide me with more details and if possible an example..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to instantiate the MultipartEntity as follows:

```
MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                                         HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE 
                                                       ) ;
```

This worked for me.

By default the [`MultipartEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html) is instantiated with [`HttpMultipartMode.STRICT`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipartMode.html#STRICT) mode which is documented in the javadocs as "RFC 822, RFC 2045, RFC 2046 compliant" .

Can someone brief out the RFC's mentioned here for clear understanding..

Thanks a Lot